# How can i distinguish between right and wrong solutions in 2d cutting stock problem?

Tags: python, linear-programming

I have this algorithm for solving the 2d cutting stock problem based on this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/emadehsan/csp/blob/master/deployment/stock_cutter.py) (Linear programming using OR-tools) in python.

My code with the drawing function can be found [here](https://codefile.io/f/d3EonkGPim)

Basically, the algorithm is divided into:

1- StockCutter function: This function solves the problem using or-tools.

2-getSingleSolution: This function returns the coordinates of each item.

3-drawRectsFromCoords: This function visualizes the solution.

Sometimes the algorithm gives the correct solution like this:
The first and second number are coords for point 1, the third and fourth are coords for the second point.

```
[[0, 0, 15, 15], [0, 15, 15, 30], [0, 30, 15, 45], [0, 45, 15, 60], [0, 60, 15, 75], [0, 75, 15, 90], [0, 90, 15, 105], [0, 105, 15, 120], [0, 120, 15, 135], [0, 135, 15, 150], [15, 0, 30, 15], [15, 15, 30, 30], [15, 30, 30, 45], [15, 45, 30, 60], [15, 60, 30, 75], [30, 0, 45, 15]]
```

Image:
[image]

And sometimes it gives a wrong solution:

```
[[21, 7, 36, 22], [8, 22, 23, 37], [23, 37, 38, 52], [7, 51, 22, 66], [8, 67, 23, 82], [7, 83, 22, 98], [17, 98, 32, 113], [7, 113, 22, 128], [23, 135, 38, 150], [39, 64, 54, 79], [47, 135, 62, 150], [40, 91, 55, 106], [22, 52, 37, 67], [23, 113, 38, 128], [1, 98, 16, 113], [1, 0, 16, 15]]
```

Image:
[image]

Is there a way to tell if a solution is valid or not in python?

Comment: Are you inspecting the solution status after the solve?  And if so, what does it say when the solution appears (obviously) wrong?

Comment: @AirSquid It says OPTIMAL every time

Comment: Don't link to codefile.io. Stack Overflow requires embedded code to constitute a minimum complete example.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you set the objective here:

```
for rect_id in range(len(child_rects)):
        model.Minimize(all_vars[rect_id].x1 + all_vars[rect_id].y1)
        model.Minimize(all_vars[rect_id].x2 + all_vars[rect_id].y2)
        model.Minimize(all_vars[rect_id].x1)
        model.Minimize(all_vars[rect_id].x2)
        model.Minimize(all_vars[rect_id].y1)
        model.Minimize(all_vars[rect_id].y2)
```

Each of your `Minimize` calls resets the objective.

This can be seen in this simple example:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
model = cp_model.CpModel()
x = model.NewIntVar(0, 10, 'x')
y = model.NewIntVar(0, 10, 'y')
model.Maximize(2 * x + 3 * y)
model.Maximize(y) # this is wrong
model.Add(2 * x + y <= 8)
model.Add(x + 2 * y <= 10)
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)
print(f'x ={solver.Value(x)}')
print(f'y ={solver.Value(y)}')
print(f'Objective Value ={ solver.ObjectiveValue()}')
```

Output:

```
Optimal Solution:
x =0
y =5
Objective Value =5.0 # Notice how the first objective isn't computed
```

Additionally you need to make sure you're never visualising a non-optimal solution:

```
assert status == cp_model.OPTIMAL, 'Problem not solved optimally'

output = {
        "statusName": solver.StatusName(status),
        "numSolutions": '1',
        "numUniqueSolutions": '1',
        "solutions": int_solutions # unique solutions
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I don't understand how to modify the objective instead of resetting it every time. Do I have to rewrite them using `Add`?

Comment: an optimization problem generally can only have one objective, you can add variables together and multiply them with coefficients. Do you know the objective that's required mathematically?

Comment: The main objective is to minimize waste so basically place all the items while not exceeding the area or dimensions of the parent. while using as little area as possible. Is this what you are asking? Sorry if I am not any help.

Comment: if you place all the elements the area you're using is a constant no matter the arrangement of items. There are different variants of the cutting stock problem, most commonly we want to minimize one of the dimensions used, and treat the rest as "waste".